# How to configure port forwarded link to apache on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-bit

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed apache2 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-bit system. I can locally open explorer browser and access the server on http://localhost . I asked the client for a public IP of the server. The client gave me a port forwarded link as http://xxxx****.dyndns.org:33808/ which is 404 currently. I am stuck on how to link this port forwarded link to the apache server

Comment: Is port `33808` really forwarded to the correct port on your Windows Server? Note that this will be done on the Internet-facing router, not on the server itself.